# Can't kill child process using ProcessPoolExecutor?

Tags: python, process

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
import time

def foo(num):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print(num)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as exe:
            exe.map(foo, range(1,4))
```

I'm tring to use module `ProcessPoolExecutor`. And after the main process started for a period of time, I want kill the process use linux kill command `kill -9 main_process_pid`. Then I found that only main process was killed, but child process still active.

```
user     41502 41004  5 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42009 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42010 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42011 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42012 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42013 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42015 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42025 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     42026 41502  0 16:16 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
```

after I run  `kill -9 41502` , it turned to be

```
user     45109     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45110     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45111     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45112     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45113     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45114     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45115     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
user     45116     1  0 16:17 pts/202  00:00:00 python demo.py
```

What should I do to kill all child process while closing the main process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, you can run

```
kill -- -41502
```

to kill parent process and subprocess.

---

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/2917/220963
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252349/what-is-the-difference-between-kill-pkill-and-killall

Comment: Why `pkill -9 -P 41502 ` not working?  Can you help me figuring out the difference  between `kill -- -41502 ` and `pkill -9 -P 41502`